# REST API Delete subID on a specific ID, is it RESTFUL?

Tags: php, rest, api, request, put

[Here is currently how a an assigned specific user can be deleted from a specific task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqenx.png)

[And this is a simple PUT REQUEST to add a specific subID to an ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwi63.png)

This is how it currently works, you can send user ID-s in the request body and it will update the "ParentID"
But to do a DELETE statement in a PUT REQUEST I had to add another input `"Delete"="true"`

If I do it with a DELETE REQUEST with the userID in the BODY, it doesn't work in the environment I need it to work that's why I have to use the PUT REQUEST

Is it a bad practise? How else could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put an action such as `DELETE` in a request body, by almost everyone's definition that's not restful.

You are supposed to just send the new state to the server. One way to tackle this is to take the entire JSON body from the task and send it to the server again, excluding the user you want to delete.

Comment: How would the URL look like then? `http://server.com/api/task/3` Where would the ID of the excluded user would go
Should it be like `http://server.com/api/task/3/user/2` or how?

Comment: Hi John, if you are updating the _entire_ task excluding the user you want to delete, then it must be the former. It is indeed also possible to create separate resources for a "user on a task". If you use that approach, then you can use a HTTP `DELETE` request on it, and that's also a viable design.